# How to deploying a self signed SSL certificate to multiple servers

Tags: iis, ssl, openssl

I need to create a self signed SSL certificate and the install the same certificate on two different web servers. For this specific scenario I have two web servers (Win2K3 w/ II6) in a network load balanced configuration.

I have installed the IIS resource tool kit and can use the SelfSSL tool to make a certificate. However my confusion comes from that the tool only registers the certificate on the current machine. How do I go about extracting the certificate in a form that I can then register it on the other web server?

I am not partial to the SelfSSL tool at all, so if I am going about this entirely wrong I am open to alternative instructions. I have seen instructions on how to generate .cer files using OpenSSL but I was really trying to hold off on install OpenSSL unless I really had to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Preface

These instructions are probably not of much help to anyone, since both Windows 7 and IIS 7 are [not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020-b75d4580-2cc7-895a-2c9c-1466d9a53962) anymore. However, I felt compelled to answer this question because it was currently the oldest unanswered question on Stackoverflow and I felt I could provide an accurate answer based on multiple sources.

With that out of the way, you should be able to extract the certificate generated by SelfSSL through the *Microsoft Management Console* and subsequently install it on other web servers using *IIS Manager*. Since you asked this question in 2008, the following instructions should be appropriate for your timeframe.

### Step 1: Extracting the certificate

These are the relevant steps from [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/107415/it-how-to-create-a-self-signed-security-ssl-certificate-and-deploy-it-to-client-machines/) on HowToGeek.

First, run the command `mmc` to open the Management Console:

[image: Windows run dialog]

In the console, go to File > Add/Remove Snap-in.

[image: File > Add/Remove Snap-in]

Add Certificates from the left side.

[image: Add or Remove Snap-ins]

Select Computer account.

[image: Certificates snap-in]

Select Local computer.

[image: Select Computer]

Click OK to view the Local Certificate store.

[image: Add or Remove snap-ins]

Navigate to Personal > Certificates and locate the certificate you setup using the SelfSSL utility.

[image: Navigate to certificate]

### Step 2: Installing the certificate.

Now that you have successfully extracted the certificate, the next step is to install it into an IIS web server. Again, [these instructions from SSL Store](https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/microsoft-iis-7-ssl-installation/) for IIS 7 should be appropriate for your timeframe.

#### 1. Launch IIS Manager

Click Start, Control Panel, Administrative Tools, and then select Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

#### 2. Select your server name

In the left Connections menu, select the server name (host) where you want to install the certificate.

#### 3. Navigate to the Security section

In the center menu, click the Server Certificates icon under the Security section near the bottom.Microsoft IIS 7 Step4

[image: Security section]

#### 4. Click Complete Certificate Request

In the right Actions menu, click Complete Certificate Request.Microsoft IIS 7 Step5

[image: Complete Certificate Request]

#### 5. Browse to your Server Certificate

In the Complete Certificate Request wizard, click “…” to browse and select Your Server Certificate file that was previously saved on your server’s desktop.

#### 6. Name your certificate

Enter a Friendly Name which is an internal reference name to distinguish the file later. We recommend including the CAs name and expiration date.Microsoft IIS 7 Step7

[image: Complete Certificate Request]

#### 7. Click OK

Click OK and the newly installed certificate should appear in the refreshed Server Certificate List.